# How to generate both stub and the ActivationID when registering activatable object

Tags: java, rmi

I am developing a system that uses RMI activation in order to isolate a set of similar, but independent components in their own JVMs such that if one crashes (a) it does not bring down the whole system and (b) it will be restarted automatically next time it is required.  I register one activation group per component, and then I want to register the activatable object within this group.  Looking at the public APIs there appear to be two choices for how to register an `ActivationDesc` with the activation system:

- `ActivationGroup.getSystem().registerObject`, which returns the `ActivationID` that you need if you want to subsequently unregister the object
- `Activatable.register`, which returns a stub through which the remote object can be activated and called.

But I can't find any way through the public APIs to get both the stub *and* the ID for the same registration - I can see no obvious way to obtain a client-side stub for a given `ActivationID` (without actually contacting the activator and activating the remote object at this point, which is what `ActivationID.activate` would do) nor to obtain the `ActivationID` of a given stub.

What am I missing?  Is there a way to do this without having to delve into internal `sun.*` APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. I had to reread my book chapter to refresh my memory. You are one of the few people using Activation and I have seen few questions on it in nearly two decades either here or at the Oracle/Sun Java forums.

The answer is that you're correct: you can't. The `ActivationID` appears to be really intended for internal use, along with `registerObject()`, which is ultimately what `register()` calls internally. The activated server is provided with it when it is activated: this means that it can unregister *itself*, which in turn implies that if you want to unregister an object from outside you could provide it with a remote method you can call from outside that causes it to unregister itself. I'm not aware of any other practical uses externally for an `ActivationID` offhand but if there are a similar technique would apply. Or you could provide it with a remote `getActivationID()` method of course.